# Double clustered standard (time and group) errors in R for panel data using coeftest() and heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, regression, standard-error

Hello there I'm trying to do double clustered standard errors (by group = firm and time) after runing a panel regression as below:

```
stage_1 <- stage_1 %>%
  mutate(fitted_values=fitted(regression_operating_income))


stage_2_regression <- plm(operating_income ~ interest_lag0 + interest_lag1 + 
                            interest_lag2 + interest_lag3 + fitted_values,
                          data=stage_1, effect="individual", model="within", 
                          index=c("firm","date"))

coeftest(stage_2_regression, vcov=vcovHC(stage_2_regression,type="HC0", 
                                         cluster=c("group", "time")))
```

I have two questions (the first one being more important):

*We can successfully run the regression plm(). However when we try to do the coeftest() that function takes an extraordinary long time to run and it seems to crash...

Can you help me figure out why? Are the arguments wrong in coeftest() or does it have to do with only including individual FE in the regression and then double clustering?

*If we have not tested for heteroscedasticity can you recommend what "type" argument in vcovHC we should use? Is "sss" or "HC0" moste appropriate?

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not yield any results".

Comment: I'll update the question. But the coeftest() function simply runs for a very long time and then seem to crash or not produce any output.

Comment: Strange, what returns `dim(stage_1)`?

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow. Due to the covid-19 business My partner can't access his stationary computer there until tomorrow...